# Typescript create dynamicaly union type from same interface props

Tags: typescript, types, interface

I want to create union type from brother of same interface

like below

```js
interface Foo {
  values: string[];
  defaultValue: string;
}

function fooo({values, defaultValue}: Foo) {}

fooo({values: ['a', 'b'], defaultValue: 'a'}); // this is correct example

fooo({values: ['a', 'b'], defaultValue: 'c'}); // I want to prevent this case!
// defaultValue must be 'a' or 'b'
// like tuple type 'a' | 'b'
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can achieve this by adding generic types.

```
interface Foo<K extends string[]> {
  values: [...K];
  defaultValue: K[number];
}

function fooo<K extends string[]>({values, defaultValue}: Foo<K>) {}
```

The generic type `K` will the tuple type of the `value` array. We then constrain `defaultValue` to only have the values specified in `values` with `K[number]`.

Let's see if it works:

```
fooo({values: ['a', 'b'], defaultValue: 'a'});
fooo({values: ['a', 'b'], defaultValue: 'c'}); // error: Type '"c"' is not assignable to type '"a" | "b"'
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=6&ssc=69&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0B4DSyIAekIAJgM7JlhSgDmA2gLoB8yA3gFDLIBucANgFcIZAFzJ6AOmk5GAbi7ISEeIP5gAagOHic9EIIC2AI2jyOAXw4cYgkAjDB0IZDEzY8hYuUrU6TZgAKNj4hEQAaJRU4NU1tCAtxDA9mAEp2Kxt3YNDhMQkAcjgCyILjAsZI5VV1LTDxIoKLVIU3TBz4-PpG0vLKqJq4+uQChCaW5AB6SfwoKHQocQAVAE8ABxQCgCIELYLkYAoQdDBkODIyYFoQOGN+FDB0ZDB1za24LeQAH2Qt4z2OEA)